# Distinct count in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, count, distinct

I have a table chat_matches in "cassandra". And want to get the count of all messages from_id to distinct to_id with count of rows(group by to_id).

```
CREATE TABLE chat_matches(
    chat_id uuid,
    from_id bigint,
    to_id bigint,
    message  text,
    message_send_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((chat_id,from_id),message_send_time)
);
```

Comment: You want from_id,to_id,count(*) group by from_id,to_id query?

Comment: Yes,Want to get the total chat count in person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cassandra `count(*)` is a very costly operation, need to scan all the row from all the node just to give you the count and can generate timeout exception.

So Instead of using `count(*)` maintain a counter table like the below one :

```
CREATE TABLE message_counter (
    from_id bigint,
    to_id bigint,
    count counter,
    primary key((from_id, to_id ))
);
```

When a new message appears just increment the value of count by one.

```
 UPDATE message_counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE from_id = 1 AND to_id = 2;
```

Now you can select the message count group by from_id to to_id very efficiently

```
SELECT * FROM message_counter WHERE from_id = 1 AND to_id = 2;
```